# How to evaluate the definite integral $\int_0^{a/2 }x^2(a^2-x^2)^{-3/2}dx $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, substitution

> $$\int_0^{a/2}x^2(a^2-x^2)^{-3/2}dx $$

I've been having trouble with this question for a while now. When I attempted the question I substituted $x=a\sin\theta$ and $(a\cos\theta)^3=(a^2-x^2)^{-3/2}$. 
When I solved with the substitutions what I get at the end is $\tan^2\theta$ in the integral sign. So I integrated $\sec^2\theta-1$ and got an answer which is different to the real answer. And when I checked an online integral calculator the top $x^2$ was split into $x^2-a^2+a^2$ to make two fractions. which didn't make sense to me at all because somewhere along that line the $x^2$ itself was completely removed. The online calculator is www.integral-calculator.com
I learned trigonometric substitution last night and I am not very good at it. So a detailed explanation would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Using substitution $x=a\sin t$ then
$$\int_0^{\frac{a}{2}}\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}^3}dx=\int_0^{\pi/6}\tan^2t\ dt$$

Comment: That's exactly what i did, I then expressed tan^2t as sec^2t-1 and got the answer X/(a^2-x^2)-arcsin(x/a)+c. but when i tried to solve it for a/2 and 0, it didn't work out.

Comment: I couldn't read your notes. It's better to write them with mathjax. anyway, $$\int \tan^2t+1-1\ dt=\tan t-t\Big|_0^{\pi/6}$$ it's a number!

Comment: I'll have to learn how to use mathjax, thanks. And also what i meant was that's exactly the answer i got, but when i re substitute the original values and calculate, The final answer is wrong.

Comment: What's te final answer ?

Comment: What I did was, after re-substituting, I used the same limits as were originally given a/2 and 0. The answer should be 1/sqrt3 - pi/6. but i couldn't get this.

Comment: It's the answer that you find in last integral: $$\tan t-t\Big|_0^{\pi/6}=\tan{\pi/6}-{\pi/6}-0=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}-\dfrac{\pi}{6}$$

Comment: and without bounds
$$\int\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}^3}dx=\int\tan^2t\ dt=\tan t-t=\dfrac{\sin t}{\cos t}-t=\dfrac{x/a}{\sqrt{1-(x/a)^2}}-\arcsin\dfrac{x}{a}=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}-\arcsin\dfrac{x}{a}+C$$

Comment: thank you so much, turns out my integration was correct, my substitution was wrong. But it's all good now :)

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

How about integration by parts

$$\int x\cdot\dfrac x{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}dx=x\int\dfrac x{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}dx-\int\left(\dfrac{dx}{dx}\int\dfrac x{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}dx\right)dx$$

Now choose $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=y$